# C++ custom initializer possible?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++ so please don't bash me :D

So I have defined a struct for 2-Dimensional Vectors and right now the easiest way to initialize one is as follows:

```
vec2 vec2_zero = vec2(0, 0);
```

Is it possible to instead make them initialize like this?

```
vec2 vec2_zero = (0, 0);
```

Comment: Just `vec2 vec2_zero(0, 0);`

Comment: Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: *vec2 vec2_zero = {0, 0};* is possible and preferable. Read some decent C++ book or other material about initializer lists, the whole thing is quite lot of info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec2 vec2_zero(0, 0);
```

It does the same thing as

```
vec2 vec2_zero = vec2(0, 0);
```

Comment: The end-result is the same, but it's not really the *same thing* (direct initialization versus copy initialization). :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What's RVO? (Tested with G++ 6.3.0)